# Midjourney - Creating a consistent character from a reference image

Tags: image-generation, midjourney

I hope this is the right place to post:

I've been at his for hours - I can't be the only one.  Can Midjourney do this, or not? (and if so, how?):

Here it is:

I had midjourney create a dog that is the main character of an illustrated children's book. great. saved it, noted the seed# and job.

Now all I want to do is generate the character with different facial expressions and positions (sad, happy, talking .. facing right, left)

but no matter how I prompt it - the updated character does not quite look like the "baseline" reference character.

Of course all subsequent prompts includ the URL of the reference image, the --seed ## , and usually have --iw 2
So - the overall issue comes up again and again - How can I get midjourney to make small incremental changes to a reference image? So that I can create a character and use it in successive different scenes?

Suggestions, solutions, would be a lifesaver ---  thanks!

Comment: Welcome to AI Stack Exchange. If you are not interested in the underlying technology and how it impacts your success in your task, then you are probably asking in the wrong place. Midjourney's prompt-chat channel is the best place to get help using the software. However short version is that character consistency is currently hard in most diffusion models. There are a variety of solutions possible that have limitations and take a fair bit of effort. Expect it to be more easily possible in around a year

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, it will be difficult. However, a few comments may improve your results.

Seed don't impact that much because it is not used to decide if generated image will look like a reference image or not, it is used for what specific version of generated image will look like. I.e. control the randomness.

Counterintuitively, iw also doesn't work. iw decide how close the generated image will look like the reference image. MidJourney, and majority of other AIs if not all, consider if two images have similar art style, composition, lightning, object in the images etc. What you want is only the object must be the same object but with different configurations (position, hair style etc.). There is currently no option to control object only mutation, hence iw will either give you a image that looks exactly the same as the reference image or mutate everything in the image, object or art style alike.

The key here is to be specific for the prompt. Tell MidJourney exactly you are trying to generate the same object but with a configuration change. This works the best for me. I think as of this posting, there are new development of consistent character generation that you may want to look into too.